# Removing whitespaces from String and then convert to XML

Tags: java, xml, string, whitespace

I want to remove white space from a string and then convert it to XML. This is my string:

```
<XMLDoc>
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <header>
            <msg-id>000C2990-2FBD-11E5-E6CF-FB0900F491A5</msg-id>
        </header>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <GetWorkItemsResponse>
            <cursor
                numRows="0"
                sameConnection="false"
            />
            <tuple
                >
                <old>
                    <TaskInfo>
                        ...
```

I can remove the white space using `str.replaceall("\\s+","")`. But while converting from string to XML, it is showing an error, because it removes the space between element and attribute. It gives a result of `<cursornumRows="0" sameConnection="false"/>` when the actual element is `<cursor numRows="0" sameConnection="false"/>`. The space between element `cursor` and attribute `numRows` is removed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what about using `str.replace(">\s+<","><")` so only spaces after elements are removed

Comment: Why do you have to remove the Whitespaces yourself? Shouldn't your XML parser be able to do that for you?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind removing the whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove whitespace before converting it to XML. Simply

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

will work. When you convert the XML document back to a string, the whitespace will disappear (by default - there are some options for pretty-printing as well):

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
String outputString = writer.getBuffer().toString();
```